# Running FFMPEG as background job

Tags: ffmpeg, powershell

I have a command that will extract audio from a video. That's working fine if I enter it as one line via CLI or Powershell window. However, I'm trying to run it as a background task (so that the initial task runs a progressbar whilst FFMPEG does it's work)

Someone suggested a Start-Job / ScriptBlock, and using a "do -> until" loop, checking for $job.State "Completed" That does something ... but immediately returns as "Completed" half a second later, (when the true process takes about 15 seconds)

I've read online that one possible reason is that FFMPEG takes its command input via STDIN, (which is why it's OK from the command line) and to disable that with -nostdin.

But as I know very little about Powershell - or FFMPEG - I don't know how to tie all these snippets of code together. Any suggestions? (NB: I'm just about to see if I can pipe a job to STDIN which might work)

```
function Extract(){
    $ProgressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
    $ProgressBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 35)
    $ProgressBar.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(460, 40)
    $ProgressBar.Style = "Marquee"
    $ProgressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 20

    $main_form.Controls.Add($ProgressBar);

    $V2ALabel.Font = $procFont
    $V2ALabel.ForeColor = 'red'
    $V2ALabel.Text = "Processing ..."

    write-host 'starting the job'
    

#    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $jobScript
#D:\home\cristofa\video_subs\captions\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe -i "K:\VE\Daisy VE.mp4" -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 "K:\VE\audio1.mp3"
#$ffpath="$ScriptDir\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe"
#$ArguementList='-i "{0}" -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 "{1}" -nostats -loglevel warning' -f $file, $saveOut
$ffpath="$ScriptDir\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe -nostdin -i {0} -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 {1} > output.log 2>&1 < /dev/null" -f $file, $saveOut
#$ArguementList="-i {0} -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 {1}" -f $file, $saveOut;
#write-host $ScriptDir
#write-host $ArguementList

#    $job=Start-Job -ScriptBlock{-filePath $ffpath -ArguementList $ArguementList}
# $job=Start-Job -ScriptBlock{-filepath $ffpath -arguementList $ArguementList}
$job=Start-Job -ScriptBlock{$ffpath}
 write-host $job.State;
    do {
     [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents() 
     } 
#     until ($job.State -eq "Completed")
#       while($job.State -eq "Running")
  while($job.State -ne "Completed")

    if ($job.State -eq "Completed"){
       Remove-Job -Job $job -Force
    write-host 'about to end'
    $Script:ButtonAction='V2AClose'
    $V2ALabel.ForeColor = 'blue'
    $V2ALabel.Text = "Process Complete"
    $main_form.Controls.Remove($ProgressBar)
    $Button.Text = "FINISHED"
    $Button.BackColor = 'red'
    $Button.ForeColor = 'white'
    }
}

function ShowStart(){
$Label.Visible
$Options.Visible
$ComboBox.Visible
$OptLabel.Visible
$Script:ButtonAction='Load'
$Button.Text         = "Load Software"
$Button.BackColor    ='red'
$Button.ForeColor    ='white'
}
```

The "# commented out" lines are various options I've tried

** UPDATE 14th Aug 2020 **

Not quite what I intended, but it now runs and displays limited information as it runs. (I now think that on Windows, it NEEDS a terminal window open in order to run. As a background task, there is no console window, so nothing runs)

```
$ArguementList='-i "{0}" -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 "{1}" -loglevel quiet -stats' -f $file, $saveOut
Start-Process -filePath "$ScriptDir\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe" $ArguementList
```

Now I just need to find how to alter the size/position of the terminal window programatically !!